# Katalon Studio not finding svg tag to create object

Tags: html, testing, svg, ui-testing, katalon-studio

I'm trying to create an object for drag and drop, but I've had no luck creating the object for the image nested inside of an svg tag. Is Katalon able to find svg tags?

I am able to find over images on my web app, but not when it's nested in a svg tag.

```html
<svg class="enyo-svg image" id="application_mainView_FileViewerPanel_control16_projectView1_Frame"
 preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width: 532.7px; height: 355.13px;">

<image id="application_mainView_FileViewerPanel_control16_projectView1_Image" 
xlink:href="assets/images/projects/centroCivico.svg" x="0" y="0" 
width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style=""></image></svg>
```

Comment: You need to find an input type field to send files to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Please search for input type field in source of page. You should pass file to that field.

Answer (score 1):

There is this discussion on github: https://github.com/kazurayam/KatalonDiscussion4977.

For the basic Application available [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic), HTML of the `SVG` element we are trying to reach is

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="hs-component">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="wrap">
        ...
        <div class="... demo">
          ...
          <div class="chart-container">
            <div id="container">
              <div id="highcharts-0x1te9k-0">
                <svg xmlns="http://http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>
                  ...
                  <text class="highcharts-title">
                    <tspan>Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016</tspan>
                  </text>
                  ...
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following `XPath` selector didn't work:

```
//div[@id="container"]/div/svg
```

with Katalon issuing a warning

```
com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/Page_Basic line/svg_namespace-ignorant' located by 'By.xpath: //div[@id="container"]/div/svg' not found
```

`XPath` needs to be [Namespace-aware](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

The svg node with the Namespace-uri http://www.w3.org/2000/svg can be selected by the following `XPath`:

```
//div[@id="container"]/div/*[namespace-uri() = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" and local-name()="svg"]
```

However, the target document happens to have only one node named "svg", so you can relax the predicate omitting a condition namespace-uri()="..." . The following `XPath` expression works as well:

```
//div[@id="container"]/div/*[local-name()="svg"]
```

Finally you can select the `SVG` text node by the following `XPath` expression:

```
//div[@id="container"]/div/*[local-name()="svg"]/*[local-name()="text" and @class="highcharts-title"]
```

Please, see if it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21337784)

Comment: Edited the answer with essential parts of code taken from the outside link.